# gotoAndStop oncomlete with TweenMax

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, tween

I'm trying to get onComplete (frame 5 in this case) to skip to a given frame after a series of animations. Here is what i have written so far. Shouldn't this work?

```
stop();
import gs.TweenMax;

import gs.plugins.*;

TweenPlugin.activate([DropShadowFilterPlugin]);
import fl.motion.easing.*;


TweenMax.from (redSquare_mc, 1, {x: 285, alpha: .5, scaleX:.5 }  );
TweenMax.to(redSquare_mc, 1, {dropShadowFilter:{color:0x000000, alpha:0.5, blurX:17, blurY:18, angle:45, distance:5}});


function firstFrame():void 
{

  TweenMax.from (yellowCircle_mc, 3, {x: 600, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, alpha: 1, delay: .125})
  TweenMax.to (yellowCircle_mc, 3, {x: 300, scaleX: .5, scaleY: .5, alpha: .5, ease:Back.easeInOut, delay: 2, onComplete: toNextFrame});

}
firstFrame();

function toNextFrame():void
{
  gotoAndStop("5");
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? are you trying to skip to the same frame you're stopping on? also can you put you're code inside the proper tags to give it highlighting and make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `gotoAndStop("5")` to `gotoAndStop(5)`. The function takes Number arguments for frame numbers and String arguments for frame labels.

Answer (score 1):

you have to send param array on function to work perfectly.

```
stop();
import gs.TweenMax;

import gs.plugins.*;

TweenPlugin.activate([DropShadowFilterPlugin]);
import fl.motion.easing.*;


TweenMax.from (redSquare_mc, 1, {x: 285, alpha: .5, scaleX:.5 }  );
TweenMax.to(redSquare_mc, 1, {dropShadowFilter:{color:0x000000, alpha:0.5, blurX:17, blurY:18, angle:45, distance:5}});


function firstFrame():void 
{

  TweenMax.from (yellowCircle_mc, 3, {x: 600, scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, alpha: 1, delay: .125})
  TweenMax.to (yellowCircle_mc, 3, {x: 300, scaleX: .5, scaleY: .5, alpha: .5, ease:Back.easeInOut, delay: 2, onCompleteParams:[yellowCircle_mc],onComplete: toNextFrame});

}
firstFrame();

function toNextFrame(mc:MovieClip):void
{
  gotoAndStop("5");
}
```